# How can I load an image on a View Controller window?

Tags: objective-c, ios, graphics, uikit

*(Note: when I first started my project I chose to use StoryBoards so I don't seem to have access to any .nib files, in case such access will be needed for what I'm asking for here..)*

I want to create a method that takes an image and the necessary coordinate parameters and loads an image at a specific position on my current View Controller's window whenever I call that method.

I'm not asking for the exact method obviously because for the time being I can't even load one single image! :)

I haven't experimented with graphics on iOS before but I went through the documentation and it was quite confusing so I decided to ask for some clarifications that might help me and others on the matter.

Apparently, I need to create an ImageView object that will hold the image I want inside it. However, there is no mention in the documentation on how to actually & eventually ***load*** the image on the window. Also, there is no actual explanation about **what a superView is**. Is the SuperView the ***first*** UIView object that ***I*** will be creating  or is it created for me by the system and I can have access to it by calling `self.view` ? Do I need to add each UIView object I'm creating as a subclass to that first SuperView? By subclassing view am I defining the way in which they will overlap each other on the screen?

Here's the code I'm using, for testing purposes, trying to load one image on the screen:

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()
{
    UIView *myView;            
    UIImage *myImage;
    UIImageView *myImageView;
}

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self) 
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // defining the size of my UIView..
    CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);

    // creating the UIView object
    myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

    // loading my image (a red square) into a UIImage object..
    myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:(@"userCell.png")];

    // creating a UIImageView object that will hold my myImage..
    myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

    // trying to make my Image load to the screen by adding the object that is 
    // encapsulating it to the UIView I created..

    [myView addSubview:myImageView];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // defining the size of my UIView..
    CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);

    // creating the UIView object
    myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

    // loading my image into a UIImage object..
    myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"userCell.png"];

    // creating a UIImageView object that will hold my myImage..
    myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];

    // trying to make my Image load to the screen by adding the object that is 
    // encapsulating it to the UIView I created..

    [myView addSubview:myImageView];
    [self.view addSubView:myView];
```

Comment: You seem to have edited you answer, but the original version was working fine for me. Judging by your original addition, what this meant was that I had to create a UIView object and set that to be my SuperView and that seemed to solve the problem. I don't know why you changed your original version, but I will try the new one as well.

Comment: because in original answer I was assigning my custom view as my main view, but custom size is not same as the screen size so it shows black background, now try original answer with this viewRect: CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 460); it will not show black background

Comment: OK I think I now understand what you did: in your original version the super view became the view holding my image (so the super view "shrunk" down to the size of a square) where as in your new edited version, my image is added as a sub view to the super view (with the latter keeping its original size, which is the size of the whole of the screen)

Comment: Cool I got it! Thank you so much, now moving on! :)

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
[myImageView setFrame:viewRect];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

Basically you need to define the frame the subview (in your case a UIImageView) will be displayed, then add this view to your view controller's main view (that's what self.view is).
No need to wrap the ImageView in a UIView, since UIImageView is a UIView itself.